# Question about text in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I know the fix to this is probably rather easy, but how would I go about getting a line of HTML to appear like this:

> 22 West Washngton St.
> Northbrook, IL 39492

Instead of:

> 22 West Washington St.
>
> Northbrook, IL 39492

Essentially, how do I go about eliminating that space between my lines of text? I am currently using `<p>` tags on both seperate tags. If I put them within the same `<p>` tag, they simply line up next to each other.

Comment: post your code for more help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `<p>` for each *line*. They are lines of an address, not separate paragraphs. Use a line break instead (`<br>`). As a side effect, that will eliminate the margin that you dislike.

Answer (score 2):

There are a million and one ways to do this..

I would recommend the first solution - as it seems the 'proper' way to do it IMHO.

It sounds like you just need to use a line break () after the .st

```
<p>22 West Washngton St. </br>
Northbrook, IL 39492</p>
```

Just to add to other ways to do this - one way is.
one would be to use a span tag and a break after st.

```
<span>22 West Washngton St. </br>
Northbrook, IL 39492</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
<p>22 West Washngton St.<br />
   Northbrook, IL 39492</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag is meant to surround paragraphs of text.  If you don't want this functionality -- and you don't in this case -- simply use `<br />` tag between the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into the head tag or your common css.

```
<head>
<style> 
p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
</style>
</head>
```

Use the Firebug in Mozilla Firefox to review CSS at runtime. if there are any more css conflicting particularly at your instance.

Comment: Should we not be guiding people to using external style sheets?